# update cassandra field using string concatenation

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I am trying to update an existing string column in cassandra table.

For example i want to append domain id in front of username.

Following is my table

```
id, username
1, agaikwad
2, xyz
```

I want to write cql to update above table to reflect following

```
id, username
1, homeoffice\\agaikwad
2, homeoffice\\xyz
```

Following is what I have tried

```
update users set username = 'homeoffice\\' + username where id = <id>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not allowed in C* because it implicitly requires a read before a write which is a bad practice with C* (and an expensive proposition in a distributed system). For a similar behavior you could store this field as a list of strings, lists support the append operation and you would be able to concatenate on the application side.

Comment: It's also a good practise to have separate columns for separate things. If you want to store `office` in your table, just create a column for it.

Comment: I see @shutty We were trying to avoid that because that needs code changes in java. By doing update i could get away with Java code changes